# How to get the entity bundle class from $form_state->getFormObject->getEntity()?

Tags: entities, 9

In `hook_form_alter()`, I want to perform some operations using an entity bundle class.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context): void {
  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  Assert::methodExists($form_object, 'getEntity');
  $flagging_entity = $form_object->getEntity();
  Assert::isInstanceOf($flagging_entity, '\Drupal\mymodule\Entity\Bundle\FlaggingBundle');
```

This assert fails.

If I try calling a method in the entity bundle directly:

```
  $flagging_entity->myEntityBundleMethod()
```

It also fails:

> Error: Call to undefined method
> Drupal\mymodule\Entity\Bundle\FlaggingBundle::myEntityBundleMethod()

The entity in question is actually a flagging entity, but the entity bundle is not getting picked up. (Perhaps because I am getting the entity with [->getEntity()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormInterface.php/function/EntityFormInterface%3A%3AgetEntity/9.4.x)?

How am I supposed to get the bundle class inside hook_form_alter()?

Comment: You need to provide a string, or better add a use statement at the top of the php file and provide as class argument FlaggingBundle::class

Comment: @4uk4 Thanks for the correction; I made a mistake when transcribing my code here.  However, even if I remove the assertion and call the method directly, I still get an error-- it seems Drupal isn't providing the entity bundle in this case.

Comment: But the error message in the second try shows Drupal storage is providing the correct bundle class instance? So this error itself is inconclusive if the method is really defined in the class.